# Spotify Error Code 403 - This request requires user authentication

Tags: php, curl, spotify

I want to add tracks to my PRIVATE Spotify playlist by php - but i don´t get it done. I´m always getting the error message

> Error Code 403 - This request requires user authentication.

I'm not the good in the spotify api. Can someone help me out? This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$method = 'POST';

$credentials = "Client ID:Client Secret";

$headers = array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response_1 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response_1 = json_decode($response_1, true);
var_dump($response_1);

$token = $response_1['access_token'];
echo $token."<br>";

$headers_2 = array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));

$url_2 =  'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/example/playlists/playlist_example_id/tracks';
$postargs = '?uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A4xwB7i0OMsmYlQGGbtJllv';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response_2 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response_2 = json_decode($response_2, true);
var_dump($response_2);
```

Comment: where are you find knowledge for connect API spotify ?

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com

Comment: I suggest you use / look into https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php

Comment: I there no way to edit my code to get it work?

Comment: @SvenJanning the error message is self explaining, isn't it?

Comment: It is - but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Is there no one who can / wants to help me on this? I don´t know, where to begin.